# JQuery Ideals Forms Intergration

Tags: jquery, forms, contacts

I am trying to recreate the demo for ideal forms ( http://elclanrs.github.com/jq-idealforms/ )
so i can get a full understanding on how each section works so i can create some great looking forms.

However i am having a few issues with the intergration

1) the if  use class ie9...... in the  of the html is not working. It is making the entire page free from css.

2) I cannot get the checkboxes or radio buttons to display despite having the image locations correct in the css.

3) the validation errors are not appearing, but i do not understand how to do these are the instructions are complicated for a jquery noob.

As mentioned above i am a noob with jquery, i would appreciate any help regardless of how small, to help me get my form working. I need to create 3 forms using this pluggin so that is the reason for me wanting a thorough understanding of each component as i will use each aspect at least once.

A link to my webpage is here https://dl.dropbox.com/u/104598901/Website/contact.html

Thank you for the help, i am appreciative for anything you can contribute.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the obvious spot, i did not relise i had that many j-query scripts loaded on the page.

I have not removed these and updated the order of the scripts.

Do you have any videos of how this is intergrated as i cannot get this to work in ie9 or get my checkboxes or radios to load.

The locations of the files are 100% correct in the css so unsure?

Comment: @elclanrs - I forgot to mension previously that when using only one script the text appears, i understand how the filters and everything work now so thank you so much!
The only issue i have now is getting the checkboxes, radios and ticks and crosses to appear. I have checked the source to the images is correct and they are. I even tested it in the browswer as a double check.

Any Ideas?

Thanks